# C4000XG router advanced SSID config

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration

I recently received a new C4000XG router/access point from CenturyLink, and my 7-yr-old HP printer would no longer connect to WiFi ("invalid WPA passphrase").

In an HP forum, I learned that it was necessary to use an SSID specific to 2.4 GHz rather than the single "flexible" one this unit broadcasts by default. In the router's wireless configuration, this comes under "advanced SSID configuration".

I tried enabling a specific SSID for "SSID 2 - 2.4 GHz" which still didn't work with my printer. But there are 2 other choices: "SSID 3 - 2.4 GHz" and "SSID 4 - 2.4 GHz". Why are there these 3 choices? How do they differ? Might one of the other 2 succeed where the first did not? There are similarly 3 choices for 5 GHz SSIDs.

Comment: Do you have any _other_ Wi-Fi access points / routers advertising that same SSID?

Answer (score 2):

> In an HP forum, I learned that it was necessary to use an SSID specific to 2.4 GHz rather than the single "flexible" one this unit broadcasts by default. In the router's wireless configuration, this comes under "advanced SSID configuration".

The real problem is a bit more general – these old HP printers cannot deal with SSIDs that they see *multiple* advertisements for.

Having your dual-band router set up for "single/flexible" vs "separate" SSIDs is not exactly the problem – I believe those HP printers only have 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi radios anyway, so they don't *know* whether you have a 5 GHz SSID at all or whether it matches the 2.4 GHz one or not.

However, if the printer sees multiple beacons for the same SSID, even on the *same* band (e.g. if you have two routers, or a "mesh" Wi-Fi system) then it will get very confused (it seems that each received beacon from the "wrong" AP interrupts the WPA authentication attempt).

> Why are there these 3 choices? How do they differ?

They just let your router advertise multiple networks at once (e.g. you could have personal and "guest" Wi-Fi networks). Usually each advertised SSID would be made to correspond to its own VLAN and IP subnet, instead of all of them leading to the same subnet.

If you have multiple routers/APs for the main Wi-Fi network, you could probably use this functionality to create a dedicated SSID for the printer only.